# Repository item grid lookupedit focus filter row

Tags: vb.net

I have a Devxpress Repository Item Grid Lookupedit binded to an xtragrid column, how can I automatically set focus to a FILTER ROW in Repository Item Grid Lookupedit when Repository Item Grid Lookupedit Opens?

Comment: Hello please look at [ask] and also at [mcve]

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour], if you can